# Function to start video

Tags: javascript, video, embed

How could initiate a function JS at the time when the video starts ?

```
<embed  id="bgvid" src="video.mp4" controller="false" showcontrols="0"></embed>
```

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678689/detect-if-html5-video-is-playing-or-paused-and-show-or-hide-a-div-accordingly/28680614#28680614) that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use an embed element? If you use the video element it has a lot more programability , you can use either the loadeddata event or the loadstart depending on when you need to initiate the function (loadeddata runs the first time when a part of the video can be rendered, loadstart runs when the video starts loading) source : http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#mediaevents

Comment: if necessary , since not know why to put the video tag to play bends hear audio and do not know why.