# video poster on pause

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

I'm using the following trick to avoid the bug of videos caching in chrome

```
$("video").each(function(index){
            $(this).get(0).load();
            $(this).get(0).addEventListener("canplaythrough", function(){
                this.play();
                this.pause();
            });
        });
```

The thing is, that it messes with the poster image (which is not the first frame in the video)

All the solutions I see to returning to the poster is reloading the video - won't it get me back to the same trouble?

So in short:
How do I get the poster image back after the play/pause...

Comment: You could add event listener on pause. When video is paused then display a div with a poster image over the video element.

Comment: but won't it hide the play and the controls?

Comment: You could add an event on clicking the poster to play the video again and hide the poster.

Comment: but I will hide the nice play button in this case - right?

Comment: @Boaz Take a look on the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akmozo/fbc7nn0o/) on [my answer for this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28680614/2256820), you have just to change the text with the poster of your video and adapt the size of the div as you want.

Comment: @sunpietro- if you want to phrase an answer, be my guest...